# How to separate characters in String by whitespace with multiple strides?

Tags: swift, string, foundation

I have a working function that separates every n character with whitespace, which works fine.

Here is the code (Swift 5):

```
extension String {
    /// Creates a new string, separating characters specified by stride lenght.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - stride: Desired stride lenght.
    ///   - separator: Character to be placed in between separations
    func separate(every stride: Int, with separator: Character) -> String {
        return String(self.enumerated().map { $0 > 0 && $0 % stride == 0 ? [separator, $1] : [$1] }.joined())
    }
}
```

This prints an example string of 1234123412341234 like this

```
1234 1234 1234 1234
```

Now, how can i separate this string 1234123412341234 with multiple strides, for example white space to be set after 4th, then after 6th and then after 5th character, like this:

```
1234 123412 34123 4
```

Comment: How generalized of a solution do you need? Or are you just dealing with fixed sized strings and groups?

Comment: Well, @Alexander-ReinstateMonica, I would like to have a function like in my code example, where you can pass an array of [Int] as an argument, so you can have a function, where you can choose how many strides you need and how long will the strides be. I would not prefer just a function with static strides, like [4, 6, 5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do this:

```
// Prints sequences of bools using 1/0s for easy reading
func p<S: Sequence>(_ bools: S) where S.Element == Bool {
    print(bools.map { $0 ? "1" : "0"}.joined())
}

// E.g. makeWindow(span: 3) returns 0001
func makeWindow(span: Int) -> UnfoldSequence<Bool, Int> {
    return sequence(state: span) { state in
        state -= 1
        switch state {
            case -1: return nil
            case 0: return true
            case _: return false
        }
    }
}

// E.g. calculateSpacePositions(spans: [4, 6, 5]) returns 000100000100001
func calculateSpacePositions<S: Sequence>(spans: S)
    -> LazySequence<FlattenSequence<LazyMapSequence<S, UnfoldSequence<Bool, Int>>>>
    where S.Element == Int {
    return spans.lazy.flatMap(makeWindow(span:))
}

extension String {
    func insertingSpaces(at spans: [Int]) -> String {
        let spacePositions = calculateSpacePositions(spans: spans + [Int.max])
//      p(spacePositions.prefix(self.count))
        let characters = zip(inputString, spacePositions)
            .flatMap { character, shouldHaveSpace -> [Character] in 
            return shouldHaveSpace ? [character, "_"] : [character]
        }

        return String(characters)
    }
}


let inputString = "1234123412341234"
let result = inputString.insertingSpaces(at: [4, 6, 5])
print(result)
```

The main idea is that I want to `zip(self, spacePositions)`, so that I obtain a sequence of the characters of `self`, along with a boolean that tells me if I should append a space after the current character.

To calculate `spacePositions`, I first started by making a function that when given an `Int` input `span`, would return `span` `false`s followed by a `true`. E.g. `makeWindow(span: 3)` returns a sequence that yields `false, false, false, true`.

From there, it's just a matter of making one of these windows per element of the input, and joining them all together using `flatMap`. I do this all lazily, so that we don't actually need to store all of these repeated booleans.

I hit one snag though. If you give the input `[4, 6, 5]`, the output I would get used to be `4` characters, space, `6` characters, space, `5` characters, end. The rest of the string was lost, because `zip` yields a sequence whose length is equal to the length of the shorter of the two inputs.

To remedy this, I append `Int.max` on the `spans` input. That way, the space positions are `000010000001000001 ...now followed by Int.max falses`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alexander for taking your time to provide a working solution and explanation. This helped a lot :)

Comment: @Miki Let me know if you have further questions :)

Answer (score 1):

```
func separate(text: String,every stride: [Int], with separator: Character)->String {
    var separatorLastPosition = 0 // This is the last separator position in text
    var myText = text
    if text.count < stride.reduce(0,+){
        return text //if your text length not enough for adding separator for all stride positions it will return the text without modifications.you can return error msg also
    }else{
        for (index, item) in stride.enumerated(){
           myText.insert(separator, at:myText.index(myText.startIndex, offsetBy: index == 0 ? item : separatorLastPosition+item))
           separatorLastPosition += item+1
        }
        return myText
    }
}

    print(separate(text: "12345678901234567890", every: [2,4,5,2], with: " "))
    //Result -- 12 3456 78901 23 4567890
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I've been looking for

Comment: Yikes, this is pretty sloppy Swift code. I would suggest you improve some things: 1) consistent spacing around commas and `else`, 2) don't iterate over indices, use `enumerated()`, 3) this doesn't actually work for OP's test case `separate(text: "1234123412341234", every: [4, 6, 5], with: " ")`, it just returns `return text` 4) there's lots of similar variables, and it's not clear what they do, and opens many questions: What's `index`? What makes it different from `j`? Why is `j == 0` special cased?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica sir, can you please checked the updated code?

Comment: 1) The spacing is still an absolute mess 2) `separatorLastPosition` should be a `String.Index`, not an `Int`. It should start at `myText.startIndex`, and get advanced in every loop iteration. As it currently is, this code isn't doing an `O(n)` walk through the string on every loop. 3) returning `text` doesn't really make much sense. It's better to `throw` or `return nil`.

Answer (score 1):

```
func separateCharcters(numbers: String, every: inout [Int], character: Character) ->String{
    var counter = 0
    var numbersWithSpaces = ""

    for (_, number) in numbers.enumerated(){

        numbersWithSpaces.append(number)

        if !every.isEmpty{
            counter += 1
            if counter  == every.first!{
                numbersWithSpaces.append(character)
                every.removeFirst()
                counter = 0
            }
        }
    }
    return numbersWithSpaces
}
```

```
Test Case
var numberArray = [4, 6, 5]
separateCharcters(numbers: "1234123412341234", every: &numberArray, character: " ")
```

```
Return Result = "1234 123412 34123 4"
```